# Trying to Add One further condition to Function

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using this function and it's working fine but when it does not find any relevant strings from `Category` to `Col"1"` then it stops.

I am trying to add one condition in the below function that is if `Col"1"` strings are not matched with `Category` strings then there are strings with the name of `"Permanent"` in the `Col"1"` so the function will go for the `"Permanent"` along with the `Condition`.

If the string matches then the same below function will work. Your help will be much appreciated.

If this function can be converted to the VBA Function from Query it will be a great help.

```
Private Function GetHtmlValues(Category As String, Condition As String) As HtmlValues

Dim Result As HtmlValues
Dim TblHtmlValues As ListObject
Dim TableAddress As String
Dim strQuery As String
Dim Query As WbkQuery

Set TblHtmlValues = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4")
TableAddress = TblHtmlValues.Range.Address
TableAddress = Replace(TableAddress, "$", "")


strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & LISTS_SHEET_NAME & "$" & TableAddress & "]" & _
    " WHERE Category = '" & Category & "'" & _
    " AND Condition = '" & Condition & "'"
    
Set Query = New WbkQuery
Query.ExecuteSql (strQuery)
While Not Query.RS.EOF
    
    Result.ConditionDescription = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(Query.RS.Fields("Condition Description"))
    Result.Description1 = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(Query.RS.Fields("Description 1"))
    Result.Description2 = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(Query.RS.Fields("Description 2"))

    Query.RS.MoveNext
Wend


Set TblHtmlValues = Nothing
Set Query = Nothing

    GetHtmlValues = Result
End Function
```

Comment: What is a WbkQuery?  As far as I know, that's not an Excel object.  And what is `Col"1"` supposed to mean in your question?  I'm having a hard time relating your question to your code.

Comment: Yes its not an excel Object but creates a new connection for sql to run, and  it works in Excel. It returns the record set and created a loop on records which it takes one by one.

Comment: Is "Permanent" a value in the Condition column, or in the Category column?

Comment: Sir Category Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but you should see the general idea:

```vb
'Return an HTMLValues object for matching record, else return Nothing
Private Function GetHtmlValues(Category As String, Permanent As String, Condition As String) As Htmlvalues

    Dim Result As Htmlvalues
    Dim TblHtmlValues As ListObject
    Dim TableAddress As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim Query As WbkQuery
    
    TableAddress = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4").Range.Address
    TableAddress = Replace(TableAddress, "$", "")
    
    Set Query = New WbkQuery
    'Try the first query...
    Query.ExecuteSql CategoryConditionSql(TableAddress, Category, Condition)
    
    Set Result = RSToHtmlValues(Query.RS)
    
    'If no result from first query then run the second using `Permanent`
    If Result Is Nothing Then
        Query.ExecuteSql CategoryConditionSql(TableAddress, Permanent, Condition)
        Set Result = RSToHtmlValues(Query.RS)
    End If
    
    GetHtmlValues = Result
End Function

'Construct SQL for Category/Condition query
Function CategoryConditionSql(TableAddress As String, Category As String, Condition As String)
    Dim strQuery As String
    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & LISTS_SHEET_NAME & "$" & TableAddress & "]" & _
        " WHERE Category = '" & Category & "'" & _
        " AND Condition = '" & Condition & "'"
End Function

'Return HTMLvalues object from RS (or nothing if RS has no records)
Function RSToHtmlValues(RS As Object) As Htmlvalues
    Dim Result As Htmlvalues
    If Not RS.EOF Then
        Set Result = New Htmlvalues
        Result.ConditionDescription = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(RS.Fields("Condition Description"))
        Result.Description1 = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(RS.Fields("Description 1"))
        Result.Description2 = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(RS.Fields("Description 2"))
    End If
    Set RSToHtmlValues = Result
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much fir the help you provided. When i run the function an error is populated `Compile Error: Object required` on the first  Set `Result` = RSToHtmlValues(Query.RS) @Tim Williams i do not understand why it is appearing

Comment: I literally tried hard and searched to fix the problem Sir but could not find any solution still this error exists please look into the problem. erro is https://ibb.co/5LtQKGz and new Question link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67835335/function-is-producing-an-compile-erorr/67836237?noredirect=1#comment119903516_67836237 @Tim Williams

Comment: Sir might this variable could help better `Public Type as HtmlValues ConditionDescription as String Description1 as String Description2 as String End Type` @Tim William that i have been forgot to share