# Function is Producing an Compile Erorr

Tags: sql, excel, vba, function

I have been using below functions  and i am trying to add one condition in the below function that is if `Col"1"` strings are not matched with `Category` strings then there are strings with the name of `"Permanent"` in the Col"1" so the function will go for the `"Permanent"` along with the Condition.

But now i have been receiving an compile error on the first line **Set `Result` = RSToHtmlValues(Query.RS)**

i do not know why the error is come any help will be appreciated.

```
    'Return an HTMLValues object for matching record, else return Nothing
Private Function GetHtmlValues(Category As String, Permanent As String, Condition As String) As Htmlvalues

    Dim Result As Htmlvalues
    Dim TblHtmlValues As ListObject
    Dim TableAddress As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim Query As WbkQuery
    
    TableAddress = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4").Range.Address
    TableAddress = Replace(TableAddress, "$", "")
    
    Set Query = New WbkQuery
    'Try the first query...
    Query.ExecuteSql CategoryConditionSql(TableAddress, Category, Condition)
    
    Set Result = RSToHtmlValues(Query.RS)
    
    'If no result from first query then run the second using `Permanent`
    If Result Is Nothing Then
        Query.ExecuteSql CategoryConditionSql(TableAddress, Permanent, Condition)
        Set Result = RSToHtmlValues(Query.RS)
    End If
    
    GetHtmlValues = Result
End Function

'Construct SQL for Category/Condition query
Function CategoryConditionSql(TableAddress As String, Category As String, Condition As String)
    Dim strQuery As String
    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & LISTS_SHEET_NAME & "$" & TableAddress & "]" & _
        " WHERE Category = '" & Category & "'" & _
        " AND Condition = '" & Condition & "'"
End Function

'Return HTMLvalues object from RS (or nothing if RS has no records)
Function RSToHtmlValues(RS As Object) As Htmlvalues
    Dim Result As Htmlvalues
    If Not RS.EOF Then
        Set Result = New Htmlvalues
        Result.ConditionDescription = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(Query.RS.Fields("Condition Description"))
        Result.Description1 = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(Query.RS.Fields("Description 1"))
        Result.Description2 = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(Query.RS.Fields("Description 2"))
    End If
    Set RSToHtmlValues = Result
End Function
```

Comment: In your `RSToHtmlValues()` function you're passing only the `RS` property of the `Query` object, yet you're trying to access the full `Query` object: `Query.RS.Fields(...)`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the guidance, then how it should be look like can you please post an answer. @Kostas K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `RSToHtmlValues()` function accepts only the `RS` property, you should access only this object, not the `Query`.

Just remove the `Query` qualifier:

```
'...
If Not RS.EOF Then
    Set Result = New Htmlvalues
    Result.ConditionDescription = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(RS.Fields("Condition Description"))
    Result.Description1 = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(RS.Fields("Description 1"))
    Result.Description2 = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(RS.Fields("Description 2"))
End If
'...
```

**Update:**

As discussed in the comments, `HtmlValues` is not an object. Trying to `Set` the reference as well as check for `Nothing` will generate errors.

Try the below. I had to change the `RSToHtmlValues()` function in order to be able to replace the statement:

```
If Result Is Nothing Then
```

Hope I didnt miss anything.

---

```
'Return an HTMLValues object for matching record, else return Nothing
Private Function GetHtmlValues(Category As String, Permanent As String, Condition As String) As HtmlValues

    Dim Result As HtmlValues
    Dim TblHtmlValues As ListObject
    Dim TableAddress As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim Query As WbkQuery
    
    TableAddress = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table4").Range.Address
    TableAddress = Replace(TableAddress, "$", "")
    
    Set Query = New WbkQuery
    'Try the first query...
    Query.ExecuteSql CategoryConditionSql(TableAddress, Category, Condition)
    
    'If no result from first query then run the second using `Permanent`
    If Not TryRSToHtmlValues(Query.RS, Result) Then
        Query.ExecuteSql CategoryConditionSql(TableAddress, Permanent, Condition)
        TryRSToHtmlValues Query.RS, Result
    End If
    
    GetHtmlValues = Result
End Function
```

---

```
'Construct SQL for Category/Condition query
Function CategoryConditionSql(TableAddress As String, Category As String, Condition As String)
    Dim strQuery As String
    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & LISTS_SHEET_NAME & "$" & TableAddress & "]" & _
        " WHERE Category = '" & Category & "'" & _
        " AND Condition = '" & Condition & "'"
End Function
```

---

```
'Fill HTMLvalues object from RS (or nothing if RS has no records) and report success/failure
Function TryRSToHtmlValues(ByVal RS As Object, ByRef webValues As HtmlValues) As Boolean

    If RS.EOF Then Exit Function
    
    webValues.ConditionDescription = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(RS.Fields("Condition Description"))
    webValues.Description1 = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(RS.Fields("Description 1"))
    webValues.Description2 = RecordsetHelpers.FieldToString(RS.Fields("Description 2"))

    TryRSToHtmlValues = True
    
End Function
```

---

Comment: Still the same error is appearing even using your way.

Comment: Yes here it is https://ibb.co/0ssWm4j Compile Error.

Comment: Please dont edit the original question because that makes my answer obsolete. What exactly is `Htmlvalues`? a class or a type? If it's a type, you need to remove the `Set` keyword.

Comment: Updated again, Htmlvalues are the comments looks like this https://ibb.co/TMh0spn

Comment: Remove the `Set` keyword from anywhere you assign the `Htmlvalues`.

Comment: when i remove the set it gives Type Mismatch error. https://ibb.co/DY8gHSs

Comment: You are treating `resultStruct` like it's an object but it's not. `Set` and `Is Nothing` are only used with objects. You need to remove both.

Comment: My fault - in the previous question I had assumed the (not posted) `Htmlvalues` was a class and not a Type (should have guessed from the name I suppose) .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822583/trying-to-add-one-further-condition-to-function/67824358?noredirect=1#comment119905065_67824358

Comment: @Tim Williams No worries, I assumed the same Tim. I even created a class to replicate the whole issue. (I wasn't aware of the other question)

Comment: But i do not understand why it is still having an same error that is `Compile Error: Object required` on Set `Result` = RSToHtmlValues(Query.RS) if i remove set then type mismatch error is appear.

Comment: The errors are different which means you need to fix the code in more than one places. Remove the `Set` and `Is Nothing` anywhere related to `Result`. `Htmlvalues` is not an object.

Comment: See update. I had to make a small change to the `RSToHtmlValues()` function to return a boolean so I can check if the second query needs to run.